# How to select li from ul having only one class in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to select all li elements from ul having class "one" only

```
<ul class="one">
<li class="heading">
<li class="list">
<li class="list">
<li class="list">
<li class="list">
</ul>       
<ul class="one two ">
<li class="heading">
<li class="list">
<li class="list">
<li class="list">
<li class="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easiest:

```
$('ul[class="one"] li');
```

Alternative, select `.one` but not `.two`:

```
$('ul.one:not(.two) li');
```

Comment: This isn't maintainable in the long run though unless the classes used are never changing from 'one' and 'two'?

Comment: @Brian: I'm not sure what you're getting at.  The first of my two solutions I posted does exactly what the OP is asking for, and it's simple enough to be easily maintainable.  The second does what he *might* have meant to ask for.  I think your answer is severely overcomplicated, which makes that significantly harder to maintain.

Comment: In addition to being more complicated, Brian's answer is also about half the speed of either of these.

Comment: @AndyE, Hi Andy, I'm genuinely not criticising. I just felt that the first solution would require a trim exercise to ensure there was no class of " one    " etc. The second example works great in the scenario that there's no future expansion of class usage such as <ul class='one three'>..</ul> etc.

Comment: @Brian: ah, I see what you're getting at now.  Yes, that is one case where your solution works better.  `$.trim(this.className).indexOf(" ") == -1` would also work in your filter. +1 to your answer for additional robustness.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jquery filter function to get a count of how many classes have been assigned to the element. When looking for all UL's with class 'one' only then the number of unique classes against the item will be 1. Once you have the filtered UL's you can simply select the sub LI's.

```
var listItems = 
$('ul.one')
.filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').length == 1;
})
.find('li');
```