# Select elements with a single class in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to select all elements that only have a single (given) class (and no other)

for example, let's say my page looks like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="a"> </div>
        <div class="a b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to select only the first element - because it has a single class "a", and no other classes.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select li from ul having only one class in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112301/how-to-select-li-from-ul-having-only-one-class-in-jquery)

Comment: Or this may be a better dupe: [How to select elements with exact one class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266866/how-to-select-elements-with-exact-one-class-name)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('.a[class="a"]')
```

or as @Hexa propsed:

```
$('div[class="a"]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/taYWP/

@Hexa: and it's actually the fastest! ;-) http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-attr-and-class

Comment: and aslo with : $('div[class="a"]')

Comment: Leading or trailing spaces around the attribute value will throw things off, but I would think/hope that would be a rare case.