# Select div not with classe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of divs on my site.

```
<div class="slide bx-clone"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide bx-clone"></div>
<div class="slide bx-clone"></div>
<div class="slide bx-clone"></div>
```

Now I want to select the div with jquery. But i only want the divs with the classe slide. And not the divs with the classe slide bx-clone.

How can i make that select statement?

Comment: Did you do any research before asking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519831/select-elements-with-a-single-class-in-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.slide:not(.bx-clone)');
```

That's [jQuery's `not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Or, you could filter the elements afterwards, by using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('.slide').not('.bx-clone');
```

Comment: @Cerbrus, the first option is infact CSS's `:not()` pseudo-class, not specific to JQuery. Not nit-picking, just informing that it can be used without Jquery. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('.slide').not('.bx-clone')
```